# Forming bytes bit by bit and concatenating bytes

Tags: python, arrays, bit, bitarray

I'm trying to send byte message via TCP socket. I have one static byte that is hex word `0xaa`. On static byte I need to concatenate dynamic byte which MSB is always 0 then I have bits from 6-4 which are variable (from 000 to 100) and than bits from 3-0 are also variable (from 0000 - 1000). What is the best way to do this? I've seen that I can use `bitarray` and `BitArray` class from `bitstring` but I would like to know what is the best solution for this problem. Also I'm need to know how to convert bitarray back to bytes so I can send it via TCP.

Example of what I need:

```
leading_byte = 0xaa
bit7 = 0 (bit)

options = { 'a' : 000 (bits), 'b' : 001 ...}
versions = { 'i' : 0000 (bits), 'i' : 0001 ...} 
bits6_4 = options['a']
bits3_0 = versions['i']

byte_message = leading_byte + bit7 + bit6_4 + bits3_0

socket.send(byte_message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bit shifting and ordinary `chr`:

```
byte_message = chr(0xaa) + chr((bits6_4 << 4) | bits3_0)
```

Comment: Thanks! But how to get bits6_4 as 3 bit value, or bit7 as signel bit in Python?

Comment: @user3599280: That can be done using the logical reverse stuff -- the `ord()` function with bit-masks applied using the `&` operator and shifting in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks. I found this solution easier. `leading_byte = bytes((0xaa,))
snd = '0' + string_opttion['a'] + string_version['b']
second_byte = bitarray(snd)  msg = leading_byte + second_byte.tobytes()`